# Linear homogeneous ODE system of first order

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Good afternoon.

I recently encountered the following problem to which I couldn't find a solution anywhere so far:

Given $A:D\to\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$, $D\subset\mathbb C$ open, with holomorphic entries. Does the equation 
$$u'(z)=A(z)u(z)$$
have a holomorphic solution $u:D\to\mathbb C^2$ ?

It is NOT known if $A(z)A(w)=A(w)A(z)$ for $z\neq w$. 
I already tried to diagonalize $A$ and solve the resulting system, but the basis changing matrix can lead to poles in $u(z)$...

Is there a standard method to tackle this problem? Can it be solved explicitly?

Thanks a lot in advance!